# Updating control value in listview through messagecenter

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, message

I want to update value in entry control inside ListView from another Pop up page using messageCenter approach. It is not working as expected as it is updating multiple items in list view.

My base page (PageA) has ListView

```
       <ListView
        x:Name="workList"
        Grid.Row="2"
        SeparatorColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
    ItemsSource="{ Binding WorkItems}"                   
        Margin="5"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        RowHeight="440"
        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
        SelectionMode="None"
        HasUnevenRows="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <local:LoadItemPutawayTemplate />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

LoadItemPutAwayTemplate is my content view for ListView as below

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
     compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     x:Class="Sanipex.LoadItemPutawayTemplate">

     <Grid
      RowSpacing="0"
      Padding="0"
      Margin="0,10,0,0"
      >

      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition
        Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition
        Height="auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Entry
            x:Name="OverrideLoc"
             Grid.Row="0"
            TextColor="Black"
            WidthRequest="110"
            Text="{Binding toLocation}"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            PlaceholderColor="Black"
            FontSize="20"/>

         <Button
                Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                x:Name="LocationBtn"
        Text="Override Loc"
                BackgroundColor="#25D366"
                TextColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
                BorderColor="#25D366"
        Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }"
                Clicked="LocationBtn_Clicked"/>
       </Grid>
```

On LocationBtn_Clicked i am calling the popup

```
  private async void LocationBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        var AvailableLocationPopUp = new AvailableLocationsPopUp();
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(AvailableLocationPopUp);
  }
```

Below is my Pop up page (AvailableLocationsPopUp) button click method from where I am sending the message

```
    private void PutawayBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MessagingCenter.Send<AvailableLocationsPopUp, string>(this, 
     "Location", "XYZ");
    }
```

As i have entry control in my contentView of LoadItemPutAwayTemplate, I am subscribing message in its constructor as below to update the value of entry control

```
    public LoadItemPutawayTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AvailableLocationsPopUp, string>(this, 
        "Location", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            this.OverrideLoc.Text = arg;
        }
    }
```

But this is updating values to all ListView items which are showing on UI. I just want to update the value of item from where the pop up was initiated.

Comment: You don't want to subscribe to the message in the template, you want to subscribe in the class where your WorkItems property is defined. At that point you'll update correct item in the WorkItems. Since MessagingCenter only allows one parameter to be sent, you may have to send a custom object that contains the location property along with which item the update should be applied to.

Comment: if you pass the bound item from your listview row to the 2nd page, updating it's value should be automatically reflected on the list page, since both pages are pointing to the same object

Comment: @Jason, it is updating but value is not being reflected on UI.

Comment: @Andrew is it possible to share a code sample?

Comment: "it is updating but value is not being reflected on UI" - are you using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subscribe to the message in the template, then all the ListView items will receive the message.
I have created a simple demo to simulate your app,the main code is:

LocationModel.cs

```
public class LocationModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     string toLocation;

    public string ToLocation {
        set { SetProperty(ref toLocation, value); }
        get { return toLocation; }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

LoadItemPutawayTemplate.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class LoadItemPutawayTemplate : ContentView
{
    public LoadItemPutawayTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LocationBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LocationModel stringInThisCell = (LocationModel)((Button)sender).BindingContext;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("send  msg  current update = " + stringInThisCell.ToLocation);

        string source = stringInThisCell.ToLocation;
        string result = "XYZ";

        string[] values = { source, result };

        MessagingCenter.Send<LoadItemPutawayTemplate, string[]>(this, "Location", values);
    }
}
```

LoadItemPutawayTemplate.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid
         RowSpacing="0"
         Padding="0"
         Margin="0,2,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Entry
        x:Name="OverrideLoc"
        Grid.Column="0"
        TextColor="Black"
        WidthRequest="110"
        Text="{Binding ToLocation}"
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        PlaceholderColor="Black"
        FontSize="20"/>
        <Button
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            x:Name="LocationBtn"
            Text="Override Loc"
            BackgroundColor="#25D366"
            TextColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
            BorderColor="#25D366"
            Clicked="LocationBtn_Clicked"/>
    </Grid>

</ContentView.Content>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<LocationModel> WorkItems { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WorkItems = new List<LocationModel>();

        WorkItems.Add(new LocationModel { ToLocation = "Tomato"});
        WorkItems.Add(new LocationModel { ToLocation = "Zucchini" });
        WorkItems.Add(new LocationModel { ToLocation = "Tomato2"});
        WorkItems.Add(new LocationModel { ToLocation = "Romaine2" });
        WorkItems.Add(new LocationModel { ToLocation = "Zucchin2"});

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoadItemPutawayTemplate, string[]>(this,
         "Location", async (sender, values) =>
        {
            string source = values[0];
            string result = values[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < WorkItems.Count; i++)
            {
                LocationModel model = WorkItems[i];
                if (source.Equals(model.ToLocation)) {
                    model.ToLocation = result;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        workList.ItemsSource = WorkItems;     
    }
}
```

Note:

1. Since I don't know the code of  `AvailableLocationsPopUp`, so I send the message when I click the Button.
2. To simply the UI,I modified the UI a little in some places(xaml).
3. You can get the full demo [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/MessageCenterDemo.git).

The result is :
[image]